# Laravel working with packages as modules

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.5

We're building a web app using laravel framework. our app is inteended to use packages that we also developed as modules. 
We notice that the views and pages loaded from the packages, takes to much time relative to the views which runs directrly from the app (the controllers are in the Http folder of the app..).

1) Is there a tool integrated with laravel that we can use in order to get more information about what causing the delay when switching between views? 
2) What issues might cause slowness in packages?

Thanks.

Comment: Install this debug bar https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar and see how much views and from where they're loaded.

Comment: 1) Look chrome-dev-tools, perform an audit it would give you more info 2) is your server using gzip or something? is it corretly configured?

Comment: @aaron0207 we don't using gzip,how we check correct configured ? Thanks

Comment: Are you using nginx or apache?

Comment: @aaron0207 apache

Comment: Activate `mod_deflate` and use this rules https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html in.`.htaccess`